How can I get props from children that was passed to the parent component? Next.js
Page.tsx - server comp
Create Habit - client comp
SubmitCreateHabit - server comp
Page.tsx
import React from 'react'
import CreateHabit from '@/components/CreateHabit'
import SubmitCreateHabit from './SubmitCreateHabit'

export default async function page() {
    return (
            <CreateHabit>
                <SubmitCreateHabit />
            </CreateHabit>
    )
}


CreateHabit.tsx
'use client'
import { Dialog, DialogPanel, DialogTitle } from '@headlessui/react'
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { ReactNode, useState } from 'react'

export default function CreateHabit({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => {
                setIsOpen(true)
            }} className='w-14 h-14 border-gray-600 rounded-full bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300'>+</button>
            <Dialog open={isOpen} onClose={() => setIsOpen(false)} className="relative z-50">
                <div className="fixed inset-0 flex w-screen items-center justify-center p-4">
                    <DialogPanel className="max-w-lg space-y-4 border bg-white p-12">
                        <DialogTitle className="font-bold">Create habit</DialogTitle>
                        <input value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} className='border-2 border-gray-600' type="text" name='habit' />
                        <div className="flex gap-4">
                            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}>Cancel</button>
                            {React.cloneElement(children, { title: title })}
                        </div>
                    </DialogPanel>
                </div>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    )
}


SubmitCreateHabit.tsx
import { createUserHabit } from '@/api/habit'
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache'
import React from 'react'

export default function SubmitCreateHabit({ title }: { title: string }) {

    console.log("children", title)

    const createHabit = async () => {
        "use server"
        await createUserHabit({ title: title })
        revalidatePath("/dashboard/main")
    }

    return (
        <form action={createHabit}>
            <button type='submit'>Create</button>
        </form>
    )
}


I expected to get title that was passed through React.cloneElement. However I just get undefined.
Passing props like below doesn't solve my problem. In this case I just get static value that was written beforehand.
<CreateHabit>
       <SubmitCreateHabit title={""}/>
 </CreateHabit>

